# regex capture anything between tags, match against anything between escaped tags

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file with duplication of escaped and non-escaped characters:

```
<p>&lt;p&gt;
```

I would like to find all instances of these and change these to a single instance of the non-escaped html character.  I thought I'd search for the left paren, then anything in the middle, then right paren, pattern match on anything in the middle, and try and find the escaped left paren (<) then the pattern, then the right parent (>) tag:

```
grep -R '<[^>]\(*\)>&lt;\1&gt;' *.properties|more
```

This doesn't return any data though, is it correct to catch everything with the asterisk inside a paren, then try and bring that all into the target pattern with the \1 ?

Comment: Doh, nothing like posting to catch your problem.  I wasn't matching around the thing the asterisk was duplicating, so this works: grep -R '<\([^>]*\)>&lt;\1&gt;' *.properties|more

Comment: you can post your answer and then collect rep points in 24 hrs by checking your own answer as accepted. As a benefit to the rest of the S.O. community, then this question will not show up as unanswered for months on end. Good luck and keep posting. We all have those doh moments, well most of us, anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't matching around the thing the asterisk was duplicating, so this works:

```
grep -R '<([^>]*)>&lt;\1&gt;' *.properties | more
```

Comment: Damian, it would be a good idea to also explain your answer, rather than just giving it. Otherwise, another person seeing this would only get confused as to what this whole thing means.

Comment: @Shahbaz This answer was already provided by the OP in a comment. I just put it here so that the question doesn't show up as unaswered - hence the community wiki.

Comment: Sorry I saw this from the review page

Comment: Please note that grep complains: `grep: Invalid back reference`. I've updated the wiki with the OPs answer, but it's not verifiably correct.